# Expresion regular para operar una potencia Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

necesito ayuda para poder operar una potencia que tiene la siguiente forma: 10 `<sup>18</sup>` o 10 elevado a la 18.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{

const span = document.querySelector('span');

let power = /((?:\-)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([<\w+>])\d+([<\/\w+>])/;
/* Si es que hay un signo menos luego un digito, 
luego si es que hay un punto seguido de un digito,
luego si hay una etiqueta <cualquier tag name>digito</cierre de etiqueta>
*/
var result;

const operation = value =>{

    if(isNaN(value)){

      if(power.test(value)){

        result = value.replace(power, (number, exp)=>{

        return Math.pow(Number(number), Number(exp));

        })
      }

      return operation(result);
      
    }

    return Number(value);

    }

    console.log(operation(span.innerHTML))

});
```

```css
body{
font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<span>10<sup>18</sup></span>
```

Creo que estoy haciendo algo mal en esa expresion regular, ¿Como puedo ejecutar esa operacion en consola?. Gracias de antemano :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estoy seguro de para que es toda la parte del inicio de los signos negativos y puntos, si simplificamos el problema a extraer el valor desde el span, podemos hacerlo así:

```
<span>2<sup>4</sup></span>

<script>
const span = document.querySelector('span');

let power = /(\d+)<sup>(\d+)<\/sup>/;

const operation = value =>{
    if (power.test(value)){
        let groups = power.exec(value);
        return Math.pow(Number(groups[1]), Number(groups[2]))
    }
}
console.log(operation(span.innerHTML)) // 16
</script>
```

Si vas a usarlo para potencias mejor escribir la etiqueta sup completa en vez de \w, para prevenir problemas luego.

Puede que el error que tengas en tu expresión regular tenga que ver con el hecho de que le pusiste llaves "[]" en la parte final:

```
([<\w+>])\d+([<\/\w+>])
```

Esas llaves indican que matchea con cualquier caracter que este dentro, pero tu quieres que sea tomado como parte de la expresión, por lo que dejarlo de esta otra forma, pasa a tomar efectivamente una etiqueta con dígitos dentro.

```
(<\w+>)\d+(<\/\w+>)
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda !!